# RSA: Decrypting message with public key and private key

Tags: rsa

I am trying to decrypt a message which its ciphertext in *Hex A3 BB 05 00*.
The original plain text is *8 bits* and it is encrypted by a *32 bits* RSA key.

I have successfully found the public key is $(e=947,n=2671079)$ and the private key is $(d=713604)$.

Then, I try to convert the *Hex* string to integer *00 05 BB A3* (Little Endian) $=375715$.

Finally, I calculate $C^d \mod n = 375715^{713604} \mod 2671079 = 544824$.

> Calculate in python: C**d % n

**My problem**:

1) what does $544824$ mean? Is it the original plain text or I need to further converting this number?

2) The plain text should be *8 bits*, why the result I get is larger than *8 bits*?

thanks!

Comment: In Python don't use  `** % n` use `pow(c,d,n)` this is more effective.

Answer (score -1):

Your ciphertext is `A3 BB 05 00`

In RSA, the ciphertext is always larger than the original data. In this case, the keys are 32 bits, which is 4 bytes, and `A3 BB 05 00` is four bytes

Comment: How about the plain text I get after the decryption? It will be 4 byte too?

Comment: Can you prove this statement ` the ciphertext is always larger than the original data`.  What if my plaintext is $n\hbox{-}1$

Comment: This is wrong. $N$ is an upper bound for both the message and the ciphertext - there is no asymmetry. At least as long as plain RSA is concerned ( and not something like RSA-OAEP.